# Redirect To Product Details

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Redirect To Product Details Page If hit the link of any disable product it open on another product of same Category as Product Details Page.

Comment: You want to redirect to `another product of same Category` or you want that disable product url but showing `another product of same Category` content?